# Could not find or load main class org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageMinion

Tags: mutation, mutation-testing

I tried all available answers but still getting this error while running pit mutation test. It runs fine on other system with same configuration, any help on this error will be appreciated. Thanks.

## Console log

```
Connecting to: localhost/127.0.0.1:61059
Connected
Received request: PitRequest [options=PitOptions [reportDir=D:......
12:15:49 AM PIT >> FINE : Running report with ReportOptions [targetClasses=[^com...
12:15:49 AM PIT >> FINE : System class path is .....
12:15:49 AM PIT >> FINE : Maximum available memory is 1799 mb
12:15:50 AM PIT >> FINE : MINION : Installing PIT agent

12:15:50 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : Error: Could not find or load main class org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageMinion
```

Comment: Could you provide some additional information - how are you running pitest (maven/ant/gradle/commandline)? What os? How does the system where you are experiencing the problem differ from the one where things run ok?

Comment: @henry Sorry for late response. Issue got resolved after doing fresh installation from scratch. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi @Bhushan what is  the configuration you are using . I am also facing similar issue